# Convertir expresión a fecha con formato 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss' en sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, java-ee, sql-server-2008

Tengo una aplicación Java basada en Oracle, y tengo que hacer una migración a SQL Server, donde necesito hacer convertir la función TO_DATE A CONVERT ya que SQL Server no admite TO_DATE.

La expresión que se usa actualmente para Oracle es:

```
sqlRestriction("{alias}.D_INSERT_DATE >= TO_DATE('"+ fecha +"','"+dateFormat+"')"))
```

Donde f y fecha son:

```
private static SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy 
HH:mm:ss");
String fecha = f.format(gregorian.getTime());
```

Ahora quiero convertir esa expresión en datetime con formato dd/MM/yyyy hh:mi:ss utilizando la función CONVERT de SQL Server que sustiutye a TO_DATE() de Oracle.

Lo que he hecho es:

```
crit.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("D_INSERT_DATE >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '"+ fecha +"')"));
```

El problema es que `CONVERT(DATETIME, expresión)` convierte la fecha en formato `yyyy-mm-aa hh:mi:ss`.

He probado a usar `CONVERT(VARCHAR(N), expresión)` pero me devuelve un string.
También he usado los styles de CONVERT()

`CONVERT(DATETIME, fecha, 120)` y otros, pero ninguno me convierte al formato que quiero.

He pensado que alomejor usando f.parse() en lugar de f.format obtendría la fecha y podría comparar sin usar CONVERT() pero no se si sería lo adecuado o si se podría hacer.

**SOLUCION:**

No ha hecho falta convertir la fecha a formato `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` ya que en sql server las fechas se guardan con formato `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` por tanto no tengo que convertir `fecha` a otro formato.

Comment: ¿Y por qué no haces lo contrario: creas desde Java la fecha formateada como está en la base de datos, o sea: `private static SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");` y haces la comparación sin más? Supongo que habrás verificado esta variable, para comprobar que se está creando bien: `String fecha = f.format(gregorian.getTime());`... es que me extraña que invoques un método llamado `getTime`, cuando te interesa también la fecha.

Comment: El problema es la ambigüedad del formato `dd/MM/yyyy `, por ej, `02/04/2018` es el 2 de abril o el 4 de febrero?, normalmente cuando se interactua con fechas es recomendable usar el formato ISO que no es ambiguo, tal como ya te comentaron. Sino deberías hacer la conversión a fecha del lado del servidor.

Comment: @A.Cedano entiendo que te refieres a que convierta D_INSERT_DATE a formato "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss" y comparar con lo que devuelve el CONVERT(fecha)? He modificado el enunciado para dejarlo más claro.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho he modificado el enunciado para dejarlo más claro y explicar por qué quiero usar el CONVERT().

Comment: Yo sigo sin entender del todo el contexto... ¿dónde está el dato que quieres convertir? ¿en una base de datos? si es en una base de datos...  ¿qué tipo de dato es en la fuente de almacenamiento actual, `DATETIME, VARCHAR`...? ¿o los datos vienen de otra parte, de un archivo o algo así? Eso es lo primero que debes explicar: **de dónde vienen los datos y que tipo / formato tienen**. Sea como sea, para guardar la fecha en la base de datos, lo correcto sería usar una columna `DATETIME` y guardarlos en el formato `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lo he resuelto. Estaba confundido porque no me daba cuenta que en sql server las fechas se guardan en el formato que comentas yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss y por tanto no hace falta convertirlas a dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Me alegro. En todos los DBMS las fechas se guardan en ese formato y conviene que así sea, pues ese formato no da lugar nunca a datos ambiguos como es el caso de `dd-mm-yyyy`. Por ejemplo esto: `01-02-2018` podría interpretarse como 1 de febrero o como 2 de enero... En definitiva, los formatos deben usarse solo para la vista (presentación de datos), jamás para el almacenamiento.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(date, Campo, 103) FROM Tabla;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estas utilizando SQL Server 2014 o posterior puedes utilizar la funcion [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) que recibe la expression de template/patron de formato y ademas la referencia cultura (ejemplo "es-ES")

Ejemplo

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME2(7) = SYSDATETIME();

SELECT FORMAT(@Date, 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'es-ES' )
```

Enlaces que te pueden

- [FORMAT | Devuelve un valor con formato con el formato y la referencia cultural opcional especificados.](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)